# ipaddress doesn't properly tag reserved IP in 192.0.0.0/24?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, ietf

I'm trying to setup a script using ipaddress module in python 3.x. I'm looking for making a parser looking for some info on public IP.

When checking the IP, I'm finding that ipaddress is not tagging as reserved the IP range 192.0.0.0/24.

From IETF docs :

> 192.0.0.0/24  192.0.0.0–192.0.0.255   Private network IETF Protocol Assignments.

From ipaddress docs :

> is_reserved: True if the address is otherwise IETF reserved.

The code :

```
import ipaddress
print(ipaddress.ip_address("192.0.0.12").is_reserved)
```

Output :

`False`

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The [`_private_networks`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1568-L1583) attribute in the [`_IPv4Constants`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1559) class suggests, that this IP is rather considered private than *otherwise reserved*. [`is_private`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.is_private) should return `True` here. The only network that `is_reserved` seems to be `240.0.0.0/4`.